# I need to create button that add image to datalist without save it in database or in folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I need to create an add button that adds the selected button from a file upload control to a data list without using save image to a database or even saving the image to a file. My code is not working.

**My html :**

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlFollowers" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Table" 
                        RepeatColumns="8" AutoPostBack="True"
                    CellPadding="10" CellSpacing="20" onitemcommand="dlFollowers_ItemCommand"  >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:ImageButton Style="margin-left: -5px; width: 80px; height: 80px; cursor: pointer" ID="ImgFollowers" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                    runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' commandname="test" CommandArgument ='<%# Eval("Url") %>' />
                    <br/> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

**my code :**

```
if (FUCivilID.HasFile){

      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      dt.Columns.Add("Url"); 

      DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

      dr["Url"] = FUCivilID.FileName ; 
      dt.Rows.Add(dr);

      dlFollowers.DataSource = dt;
      dlFollowers.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to achieve

Comment: And what is the problem? What is not working?

Comment: @Imadoddin Ibn Alauddin I have file upload control when I choose the  image I want then  press on add button that button add images to datalist without save image to data base I need to know how can I create that add button

Comment: @jjczopek the code in add button  not working

Comment: give it full path instead of file name